# jquery Post: request uri too long

Tags: jquery, post

So here's an interesting problem. I'm posting to a web service and I'm getting the request URI is too long. jQuery seems to be appending my data to the URL:

```
// this is dynamically generated, and can get very long
var s = 'q=string1&q=string2';

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?',
  data: s,
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

I also tried:

```
data: {data: s}
```

Same thing.

The tricky part is that I need to translate multiple items. Google requires that you pass the 'q' variable multiple times. Not an array, but the same parameter multiple times. Which seems stange. So that eliminates using a json object, because you can't have the same key twice. Hence the reason I have to pass a string.

Any idea how I can accomplish this and get the data in the request body instead of the URI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a JSONP POST request. JSONP is about passing the parameters in the `src` attribute of a script tag, and script are always loaded with GET. If you set the data type of the `$.ajax` call to `jsonp`, jQuery will disregard the `type` setting and use GET (where URI length limits apply). Sending cross-domain POST requests with AJAX is [possible](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) but rather complicated and requires the cooperation of the target server. Otherwise, you need to use some sort of proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't post to remote URIs. Apparently this is not allowed through jQuery. I had to post to my own server, then and pass the call through accordingly. jQuery will try to convert the request to a GET request, because that is allowed.

Comment: You can post to remote URIs (jQuery does not internally support it but it is easy to add support using the 1.5 [transports](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) mechanism), but most of the time that is useless due to security limitations.

Answer (score -1):

I notice that you have set: `X-HTTP-Method-Override` to `GET`,
which might be a probable reason for such a behavior.

What essentially `X-HTTP-Method-Override` does is to tell the Restful clients to override the actual HTTP method and interpret the request as what `X-HTTP-Method-Override` is set to be.

Therefore, the request might actually be working as `GET` request.
Try changing it to `POST` and see what happens.

Comment: I just want to know how to put the data in the request body. I removed that header. Same issue.